# Opening create Translation Job window is very slow

Tags: web8.5, translation-manager, performance

I'm using Translation Manager with SDL Web 8.5.

Creating a component and click Translate menu, it often takes a long time(more than 1 minute) to open the Translation Job popup window, or it never open.
(This problem doesn't always occur, but often occurs)

According to Web browser's development tool and server log, nothing happens after clicking Translate menu when the problem occurs(no error appears and no request is created).

The problem occurs on any Web browser(IE, Firefox, and Google Chrome).

I'm using Microsoft Azure as CM server and Azure SQL Database as DB.

I've already applied Hotfixes to CM and TM.

Are there any similar issues and solutions?

Regards,

Comment: Is it used TMS cloud or world server?

Comment: World Server is used.

Comment: Did you tried latest hotfix TM_8.5.0.10991 ?

Comment: To check the network connections latency between CMS and World server?

Comment: I tried TM_8.5.0.10991, but it's not improved.

Answer (score 2):

I asked SDL support about this issue, and new Hotfix `TM_8.5.0.11182` was provided.The Hotfix solved this problem.